# Getting Model class fields not working well

Tags: python, django

i'm trying to get all fields from db.Model class. For example: I have two classes A and B. Class A have 3 fields and class B have 2 but one of two fields in class B is foreign key from class A. When i do this: `A._meta.get_all_field_names()` i get and field from class B where is that field foreign key for B from A. Why?

Comment: You should show you model code to get help. ALso show the code you tried and it's output.

Comment: I'm succeed like this A._meta.fields[0].name :) Thanks!

Comment: @user2758618 yeah, exactly, please, see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works as intended, here's `get_all_field_names()`'s docstring:

> Returns a list of all field names that are possible for this model
>   (including reverse relation names).

If you don't want to see fields from related models, just read fields from `_meta.fields`:

```
[field.name for field in A._meta.fields]
```

Comment: @Ber I've actually just worked on the similar problem, so I am somewhat in the mood :)

Comment: Thanks! Didn't saw the answer :)